# Unittest with mock for django login

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-tests, django-unittest

I am writing Unittests for the Login on Django. And I have serious problems with the `get_user()`. I just can't figure out how to get through this function in test. I can't make a mock, and I can't substitute values. I think I'm wrong do it. But I don't know how do it right!

Please, I need help!

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
```

I need unittest for this simply function.

Comment: Where is `UserLoginForm` from? Can't you just use the test client, post to that view and assert that the user is now logged in?

Comment: I have overridden the form `UserLoginForm`, form inherited from `AuthenticationForm`

Comment: Can you just test the view with the test client and assert that the login works?

Comment: @IainShelvington Please, write how this do.

Comment: Added an example as a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic test for the login view, it asserts that a 200 response is returned when someone logs in. I don't think that mocks are required. For completeness you would most likely want to add tests for incorrect username/password and deactivated accounts

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class SimpleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.username = 'foo'
        self.password = 'bar'
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(self.username, password=self.password)

    def test_login(self):
        response = c.post('/login/', {'username': self.username, 'password': self.password})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: It's not what I need, but thanks for your answer...